# How to check the order in which variables activate?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a system to check in what order do variables activate in order to prevent certain bugs. I'm sorry if it sounds confusing.

Example:

I have the following Bools

`bool firstCheck`

`bool secondCheck`

`bool thirdCheck`

I want to check if the variables activate in the following order (from left to right):

`firstCheck == true` > `secondCheck == true`  > `thirdCheck == true` > `//Do code`

For simplicity, suppose that when a `variable`  is activated, the following checks continue, but the original `variable`  changes its condition to false.

I also want to check if, say, once `firstCheck`  is `true` and `secondCheck`  is `true`, and proceeds to the next check(remember that they change back to `false` ), suddenly, the variable `secondCheck`  is `true`, meaning that whatever the process was, it went "back". If that happens, I want to do some code.

I don't know if I explained it correctly if you have any doubts and would like to help, don't worry and ask them

Comment: This sounds like a state machine. Have you considered using an enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best to address the first issue of terminology, variables don't get *activated*, a better way to describe what's happening is to describe them as *set*/*assigned* or *initialized*. *Value types* are *set*, *nullable value types* and *reference types* are *initialized*, both can be *assigned*.

Depending what you need, an `enum` ***can*** be *mutually exclusive* and have multiple values.

Example:

**Given**

```
public enum State
{
   First,
   Second,
   Third,
   Finished
}
```

**Nonsensical state machine example**

```
var state = State.First;

while (state != State.Finished)
{
   switch (state)
   {
      case State.First:
         Console.WriteLine($"You are state {state}. Type something");
         Console.ReadLine();
         state = State.Second;
         break;
      case State.Second:
         Console.WriteLine($"You have progressed, State = {state}. Type something");
         Console.ReadLine();
         state = State.Third;
         break;
      case State.Third:
         Console.WriteLine($"You are good at this, State = {state}. Type something else");
         Console.ReadLine();
         state = State.Finished;
         break;

      default:
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
   }
}
Console.WriteLine($"Game over, you can type stuff. State = {state}");
```

**Output**

```
You are state First. Type something
sgf
You have progressed, State = Second. Type something
fgh
You are good at this, State = Third. Type something else
fghfg
Game over, you can type stuff. State = Finished
```

Comment: Okay, I have tried applying this to my code and everything works perfectly. Thanks for the help.